# Animated loader screen on submit of form works on laptop not on iphone using JS

Tags: javascript, svg, webview, wrapper

I have a form where the user picks, via a range slider, and then clicks on an SVG map to submit a form.  On 'touchstart click', I'd like to show an animated SVG for three seconds and then submit the form.

This code that shows loader on phone but no animation (it presents what seems to be a snapshot of the animation.  Animation works on website):

```
$('.region').on('touchstart click', function (e) {
    document.getElementById("loader").style.visibility = "visible";
    $('#region').val($(this).data('val')); // sets to region
    $('#myForm').submit();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The CSS for #loader is visibility: hidden.  If I use 'display: none' instead of 'visibility' it does not show at all.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akmiecik/fo9ntp1L/28/) that works in fiddle but not on site.

This code works (loader shows and is animated) on the laptop but the loader screen does not show up on the phone (probably due to the display issue mentioned above).

```
$('.region').on('touchstart click', function (e)  {
    $("#loader").show();
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#region').val($(this).data('val')); // sets to region
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
});
```

I am developing the app with PHP and JS from a web perspective (because that is what I know right now) and using webview to make it an app.  It's in the webview app that I am viewing on the phone.

Comment: Sounds like an client side issue so no need for the PHP tag (only add tags that are directly relevant to the issue at hand)

Comment: I didn't read all your codes. One thing I am concerning is If you use Jquery `show` and `hide`, you should stick to it. Don't use `.style.visibility` or versa vice. Jquery may have different implementation in `hide` comparing to `.style.visibility`

Comment: I've tried presenting the SVG as an object "<object style="width: 100vw; height: auto;" type="image/svg+xml" data="svg image goes here">" and through CSS as backgroud-image.

Comment: Thanks ikhvjs.  Since I don't know what is going to work, I'm trying anything I can get to work in jsfiddle.

Comment: @user2245642, what phone did you use to test with? PS: You can use @ to quote someone instead.

Comment: @ikhvjs iPhone 12  and thanks for the tip.  By the way, the animation works if I don't submit the form.  So if only use the ElementById("loader") line, I get the animated SVG popping up and then....well, there is no and then.